# Changing user process on a system process

Tags: c#

I have a little problem.The Device Manager is a list of processes. The process my application is active on my user (FoX0X). How to change the process to belong to the system (Replace "FoX0X" to "SYSTEM")? Besides that if you can not close it in the device manager? 
I tried to use the code:

```
File.SetAttributes("AppName", FileAttributes.System);
```

But this dont work.

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? Any exception or error message?

Comment: There is no error but the process still belongs to the user and not to the system

Comment: Based on the information you have provided, the realization that a file and a process are two different things might be helpful as a start.

Comment: He wants the process was not the only user to the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change users a process is running under, you may be able to do [impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx) to run a section of code as another user, but you can not modify the process itself to be running as another user.

To make your process run as SYSTEM it must be started under that user.